# What causes the current in the interior lagoons of Presque Isle State Park PA?

Tags: rivers, canoes, pennsylvania

There is canoe trail, in the interior lagoons of Presque Isle State Park PA.  No gas engines are allowed, travel is bidirectional, like a bike path most travelers make a two way trip on the same path.

While I was paddling there this summer, I noticed that the water plants a few feet under the surface all pointed in the same direction, indicating a current.  This was consistent for multiple visits this summer. The current is nearly insignificant from a paddling perspective but it does impact the plant life.

The canoe trail is indicated in the map below by a red line.  As I recall the current was flowing from west to east (left to right).  These lagoons are interconnected, on a peninsula, communicating with sheltered bays, inside of a sheltered bay.  There are no elevated locations that might be the source of artesian wells.

What causes the current in the interior lagoons of Presque Isle State Park PA?

[image: Canoe trail path]

Details about the area:

[Presque Isle State Park at PA State Parks](http://www.dcnr.pa.gov/StateParks/FindAPark/PresqueIsleStatePark/Pages/Boating.aspx)

[Presque Isle State Park at Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presque_Isle_State_Park)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lake Erie is classed as non-tidal because the tidal variance is less than [5cm at spring tide](https://oceanservice.noaa.gov/facts/gltides.html)

However (same source):

> Wind and weather conditions on the Great Lakes may create a [seiche](https://oceanservice.noaa.gov/facts/seiche.html), an oscillating wave which can be several feet high. In many of the Great Lakes, the time period between the “high” and “low” of a seiche may be between four and seven hours. As this is very similar to the six-hour time period of the tides on the ocean, it is frequently mistaken for a tide.

Since the image shows a larger body of water behind a bottleneck you could well be seeing this effect as a current flowing through that narrowed region caused by variance in water depth in the outer lake.